# Boost with vectors of pointers to object (C++ - linux)

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, boost

I'm looking at a code to organize papers. I have two classes (Author and Paper) that are interconnected through containment and pointers. I defined the serialization for both classes, but I can only save an object if I discard the information about the other class. I am completely new to object serialization and I feel I've gone as far as I could go.

**Author.h**:

```
...
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class Paper;

class Author
{
    public:
        friend class Paper;

        Author( const std::string& last_name_in = "", 
        const std::string& first_name_in = "", 
        const std::string& middle_name_in = "" );
        ...

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & first_name;
            ar & last_name;
            ar & middle_name;
            ar & display_name;
            for (int ii = 0; ii < list_of_papers.size(); ii++)
                ar & list_of_papers[ii];
        }
        ... 
        std::string first_name;
        std::string last_name;
        std::string middle_name;
        std::string display_name;
        std::vector<const Paper*>   list_of_papers;
};
```

I don't have a default constructor in Paper.h, as it doesn't make sense and I don't really know how I would go with it.
**Paper.h**:

```
...
class Author;

class Paper
{
    public:
        friend class Author;
        Paper( const std::string& paper_title_in,
        const std::vector<Author*>& paper_authors_in );   
        ...

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & paper_title;
            for (int ii = 0; ii < paper_authors.size(); ii++)
                ar & paper_authors[ii];
        }

        std::string         paper_title;
        std::vector<Author*>    paper_authors;
};
```

**test.cpp**:

```
int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    {
        Author  author1("Doe", "John");
        Author  author2("Dude", "Jim", "J");
        std::vector<Author*> list_of_authors;
        list_of_authors.push_back(&author1);
        Paper   other_paper( "A Nice Paper", list_of_authors );
        list_of_authors.push_back(&author2);
        Paper   this_is_my_paper( "What a beautiful paper", list_of_authors );
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << author1;
    }
    {
        Author  author_new;
        std::ifstream ifs("filename");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> author_new;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In Linux, I compile with g++:

```
g++ -o test -I /path/boost/ -L /path/boost/ -lboost_serialization test.cpp author.cpp paper.cpp
```

In the form presented above, the code doesn't compile and gives me a huge message. It would compile before I added object serialization, and it compiles if I remove 'ar & list_of_papers[ii];' from Author.h.

Can anybody see what I am missing?

Comment: I think you have not provided the complete path to your boost libs

Comment: could you post the error message

Answer (score 0):

```
ar & paper_authors;
```

should work directly since boost can serialize STL containers of objects provided the objects themselves are serialisable
cf : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl

Comment: paper_authors
is a vector of pointers to Author. Doesn't it change anything?

Comment: I made the modification suggested by @lezebulon. I also added
    #include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
Finally, I changed list_of_papers from
    std::vector<const Paper*>   list_of_papers;
to
    std::vector<Paper*>   list_of_papers;
and everything works fine. Does that mean one cannot save/load const pointers? Or is a more refined trick needed?
Thanks anyway for your help.